# How Can I Display a Message Box That Has No Buttons, and That Disappears After a Specified Period of Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this short code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="addedSuccess()">Add to Cart</button>

<p id="demo"></p>




</body>
</html>

<script>
function addedSuccess() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Item added successfully in Cart";
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to make the message disappear after a given period of time? I want the message to show every time the user would click on "add to cart" then disappear after a period of time without having to worry about pressing on a button to make it go away... Is there a way of doing this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use setTimeout function in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a time out function and then remove the html from the element:

```js
function addedSuccess() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Item added successfully in Cart";
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#demo').html('');
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="addedSuccess()">Add to Cart</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Removing the HTML, rather than hiding the element makes it easier to re-use it on the next click (if that's what you plan to do) - just re-set the content, rather than re-set content and visibility.

Answer (score 2):

use below code  . use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function .here 3000 meaning 3 seconds. you can change seconds as per your requirement.

The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.1000 ms = 1 second.

```
  <script>
    function addedSuccess() {
       document.getElementById("demo").style = "display:block";
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Item added successfully in     Cart";
       setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById("demo").style = "display:none";
       }, 3000);
    }
 </script>
```

or use below code to clear text

```
 <script>
     function addedSuccess() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Item added successfully in     Cart";
       setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
       }, 3000);
     }
 </script>
```

if you want to use jquery then use below code . see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/j0avjya1/2/)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head> 
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on('click','#addtocart',function(){
            $('#demo').html('Item added successfully in Cart');
            $('#demo').delay( 3000 ).hide(0);
         });
      });
   </script>
   </head> 
   <html>
   <body>
    <button id="addtocart">Add to Cart</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use JavaScript function [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)

setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("demo").style = "display:none";
}, 3000);
```

Or if you want to do with jquery try this

```
$( "#demo" ).delay( 3000 ).hide(0);
```